# java compiler error when using arrays from main method into a function

Tags: java, function, compiler-construction

```
import java.util.*;

class Practice_Sac 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //START MAIN
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("How much did the product cost?");
        double InitialCost = scan.nextDouble(); // Scans initial cost and applies commission
        double CommisionPrice = Commission(InitialCost );
        System.out.println();

        String[] PostCodes = {"Northern Territory", "New South Wales", "ACT", "Victoria", "Queensland", "South Australia", "Western Australia" }; //first array for state names
        int[] PostPrices = {25, 15, 15, 12, 20, 15, 25 }; //second array for postage prices. They match the first array

        System.out.println("Please chose your state");
        System.out.println();

        int i = 0; // displays all the states and prices accordingly
        do
        {
            System.out.println(i + " " + PostCodes[i] + " $" + PostPrices[i]);
            i++;
        }
        while (i < 7);

        int state = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("You selected the state " + PostCodes[state]);   

        CommisionPrice = CommisionPrice + PostPrices[state]; //applies postage fees to current price + commission

        System.out.println("Enter Coupon Code (Case sensitive)"); //gets coupon code
        String CouponCode = scan.next();
        System.out.println();

        double TotalCost = coupon(CommisionPrice );
        System.out.println("The total price comes to: $" + TotalCost );
        //END MAIN  
    }
        //FIRST FUNCTION
    public static double Commission(double value )
    {
    double cost = value * 1.125;
    return cost;
     }
        //SECOND FUNCTION
    public static double coupon(double CommisionPrice, String Coupon, int[state] PostPrices )
    {
        if (Coupon.equals ("BIGSALE" ))
        {
            CommisionPrice = CommisionPrice * 0.9; // 10% off final cost including postage
        }
        else if (Coupon.equals ("FREEPOST"))
        {
            CommisionPrice = CommisionPrice - PostPrices[state]; // takes away postage price
        }
        else if (Coupon.equals ("SMALLCOMMS"))
        {
            CommisionPrice = ((CommisionPrice - PostPrices[state] )* (1/1.125 ) )* 1.05 + PostPrices[state]; //takes away postage price, removes the 12.5% commission then adds 5% commision and adds postage price
        }
        else System.out.println("Invalid Code" ); // if an invalid code is given

        return TotalCost;
    }

}
```

Java Compiler error

```
    Test.java:49: error: ']' expected
        public static double coupon(double CommisionPrice, String Coupon, int[state] PostPrices )
                                                                              ^
    Test.java:49: error: ')' expected
        public static double coupon(double CommisionPrice, String Coupon, int[state] PostPrices )
                                                                                   ^
    Test.java:49: error: <identifier> expected
        public static double coupon(double CommisionPrice, String Coupon, int[state] PostPrices )
                                                                                               ^
    3 errors
```

Sorry if i formatted the code wrong, first time posting here. But the problem I seem to have is that I don't understand how these errors are happened when calling variables from the main method into the function. If I use the code inside the function and place it in the main method it works fine, but it is required that I make a function for it

Comment: Where is the compiler error?

Comment: It's int[] PostPrices. ProTipp : Check out java basics.

Comment: Not solution for your error but methods should start with lower case letter. Also variables should start with lower case letter. `int[] postPrices`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass an integer array as an argument to a function the correct syntax is :

```
public static double coupon(double CommisionPrice, String Coupon, int[] PostPrices )
{ ... }
```

Also, your call to the `coupon` function is incorrect. You are only passing 1 argument, whereas according to the above definition, it requires 3.

In the `coupon` function, you are trying to use the `state` variable where you take user input, this wont be accessible in the `coupon` function as it is a local variable of the `main` method.

Comment: Then how did i get it to work for the first function?

Comment: do you mean `double CommisionPrice = Commission(InitialCost );`? 
Look at the function signature for `Commission` : `public static double Commission(double value )`, it needs only 1 argument.

Comment: yea, and I tried changing it to what you had suggested and it's expecting .class after each time PostPrices[] is used in the function. And adding that doesn't fix it.

Comment: I don't understand, expecting `.class` ?
How are you calling the `coupon` function?

Comment: like this: public static double coupon(double CommisionPrice, String Coupon, int PostPrices )

(i think im getting all the variables i need)

Comment: Or did you mean this line?  
double TotalCost = coupon(CommisionPrice, Coupon, PostPrices, state );